# Getting term set of a user profile property in SharePoint 2010

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, metadata, taxonomy

I need to find out (programmatically) what term set is used by a certain user profile property, but I can't figure out how to do that. Any ideas are highly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, figured it out:

```
SPSite site = new SPSite(url);
SPServiceContext context = SPServiceContext.GetContext(site);
var userProfileConfigManager = new UserProfileConfigManager(context);
ProfilePropertyManager profilePropertyManager = userProfileConfigManager.ProfilePropertyManager;
CorePropertyManager corePropertyManager = profilePropertyManager.GetCoreProperties();
CoreProperty property = corePropertyManager.GetPropertyByName(propertyName);
TermSet ts = property.TermSet; // DONE!
```